# How to download css-3 filters applied images

Tags: image, css, html2canvas

I am trying to create a image editor where css-3 is used to apply filters and need to download that image for fast face of image processing.

https://jsfiddle.net/sridharn/bq6w8fx2/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var img = document.getElementById("image1");
        // filters
        var grayValue = "0.2";
        var blurValue = "1px";
        var brightnessValue = "150%";
        var saturateValue = "0.2";
        var contrastValue = "0.2";
        var sepiaValue = "0.2";
        // `filterVal`
        var filterVal = "grayscale(" + grayValue + ") "
                        + "blur(" + blurValue + ") "
                        + "brightness(" + brightnessValue + ") "
                        + "saturate(" + saturateValue + ") "
                        + "contrast(" + contrastValue + ") "
                        + "sepia(" + sepiaValue + ")";
        // set `img` `filter` to `filterVal`
        $(img)
        .css({
            "webkit-filter": filterVal,
            "moz-filter": filterVal,
            "ms-filter": filterVal,
            "o-filter": filterVal
        });
        function downloadCanvas(link, canvas, filename) {
            link.href = document.getElementsByTagName(canvas)[0].toDataURL();
            link.download = filename;
        }

        document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function () {
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); //Convert image to 'octet-stream' (Just a download, really)
                    window.location.href = image;
                }
            });

        }, false);
});
```

However the image downloaded is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can not download an image including the filters because `filter:` property tells the browser how to **render** the image and does **not edit** them, this means the image is the same but browser is showing it differently. That's why you always get an empty image(empty in the sense without filters) when you download them because original image is downloaded. You will have to use image editor to change an image.